# R - How do I add lines and text to pheatmap?

Tags: r

I am creating heatmaps using the `pheatmap()` function using the following code:

```
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap((data_matrix[,1:11]), cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, scale="none",
     show_rownames=F, treeheight_row = F, 
     color=colorRampPalette(rev(c("red","white")))(50),
     main="values", cex.main=1.2)
```

I would like to add text and lines at some positions to indicate groups and percentages.

`abline()` and `text()` don't work and with overplotting I was not successful so far.

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks,
Philipp

Comment: Very strange that `text()` and `abline()` don't work for you there... Maybe you should check the system of coordinates in use by `pheatmap`, just in case you would be plotting your text and lines out of the graphic frame...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the `pheatmap` function you will see that, after some fiddling with the data it calls the `heatmap_motor` function.

Looking at this function (it is not exported, so you will have to type `pheatmap:::heatmap_motor` to see its source code) you will see that it uses functions from the `grid` package to plot the heatmap, hence using `abline` or `text` won't work, but `grid.abline` or `grid.text` will!

For instance (note that the coordinates were found by a trial-and-error process):

```
library(pheatmap)
library(grid)

a <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
pheatmap(a, cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F)

grid.text(1:100, x=rep(seq(0.05, 0.91, length.out=10), 10), 
          y=rep(seq(0, 1, 0.1)+0.05, each=10))
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the hint to use `grid.abline` and `grid.text` instead. In the end I used `grid.text` and `grid.lines` as I could not limit the length of `grid.abline`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `display_numbers` option in `pheatmap`. For example,

```
library(pheatmap)

a <- matrix(rnorm(90), 9, 10)
txt <- matrix(sample(letters, replace = TRUE, 90), 9, 10)
pheatmap(a, cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, display_numbers = txt)
```

The result figure: [pheatmap with texts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0OvE.png)