# pheatmap: Color for NA

Tags: r, na, pheatmap

Using R package pheatmap to draw heatmaps. Is there a way to assign a color to NAs in the input matrix? It seems NA gets colored in white by default.
E.g.:

```
library(pheatmap)
m<- matrix(c(1:100), nrow= 10)
m[1,1]<- NA
m[10,10]<- NA
pheatmap(m, cluster_rows=FALSE, cluster_cols=FALSE)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

It is possible, but requires some hacking.

First of all let's see how `pheatmap` draws a heatmap. You can check that just by typing `pheatmap` in the console and scrolling through the output, or alternatively using `edit(pheatmap)`.

You will find that colours are mapped using

```
mat = scale_colours(mat, col = color, breaks = breaks)
```

The `scale_colours` function seems to be an internal function of the `pheatmap` package, but we can check the source code using

```
getAnywhere(scale_colours)
```

Which gives

```
function (mat, col = rainbow(10), breaks = NA) 
{
    mat = as.matrix(mat)
    return(matrix(scale_vec_colours(as.vector(mat), col = col, 
        breaks = breaks), nrow(mat), ncol(mat), dimnames = list(rownames(mat), 
        colnames(mat))))
}
```

Now we need to check `scale_vec_colours`, that turns out to be:

```
function (x, col = rainbow(10), breaks = NA) 
{
    return(col[as.numeric(cut(x, breaks = breaks, include.lowest = T))])
}
```

So, essentially, `pheatmap` is using `cut` to decide which colours to use.

Let's try and see what `cut` does if there are NAs around:

```
as.numeric(cut(c(1:100, NA, NA), seq(0, 100, 10)))
  [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
 [29]  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6
 [57]  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9
 [85]  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 NA NA
```

It returns NA! So, here's your issue!

Now, how do we get around it?
The easiest thing is to let `pheatmap` draw the heatmap, then overplot the NA values as we like.

Looking again at the `pheatmap` function you'll see it uses the `grid` package for plotting (see also this question: [R - How do I add lines and text to pheatmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241333/r-how-do-i-add-lines-and-text-to-pheatmap))

So you can use `grid.rect` to add rectangles to the NA positions.
What I would do is find the coordinates of the heatmap border by trial and error, then work from there to plot the rectangles.

For instance:

```
library(pheatmap)
m<- matrix(c(1:100), nrow= 10)
m[1,1]<- NA
m[10,10]<- NA

hmap <- pheatmap(m, cluster_rows=FALSE, cluster_cols=FALSE)
# These values were found by trial and error
# They WILL be different on your system and will vary when you change
# the size of the output, you may want to take that into account.
min.x <- 0.005
min.y <- 0.01
max.x <- 0.968
max.y <- 0.990
width <- 0.095
height <- 0.095

coord.x <- seq(min.x, max.x-width, length.out=ncol(m))
coord.y <- seq(max.y-height, min.y, length.out=nrow(m))

for (x in seq_along(coord.x))
  {
  for (y in seq_along(coord.y))
    {
    if (is.na(m[x,y]))
        grid.rect(coord.x[x], coord.y[y], just=c("left", "bottom"),
                  width, height, gp = gpar(fill = "green"))    
    }
  }
```

A better solution would be to hack the code of `pheatmap` using the `edit` function and have it deal with NAs as you wish...

Answer (score 11):

Actually, the question is easy now. The current pheatmap function has incorporated a parameter for assigning a color to "NA", na_col. Example:

```
na_col = "grey90"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can enable assigning a colour by using the developer version of pheatmap from [github](https://github.com/raivokolde/pheatmap). You can do this using devtools:

```
#this part loads the dev pheatmap package from github
if (!require("devtools")) {
  install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
  library(devtools)
}
install_github("raivokolde/pheatmap")
```

Now you can use the parameter "na_col" in the pheatmap function:

```
pheatmap(..., na_col = "grey", ...)
```

(edit)
Don't forget to load it afterwards. Once it is installed, you can treat it as any other installed package.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using `heatmap.2` from `gplots` instead, there's a convenient `na.color` argument. Taking the example data `m` from above:

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(m, Rowv = F, Colv = F, trace = "none", na.color = "Green")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the NAs to be grey, you can simply force the "NA" as double.

```
m[is.na(m)] <- as.double("NA")
pheatmap(m, cluster_rows=F, cluster_cols=F)
```